# Flex, ActionScript - StringUtil

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I am trying to edit an already existing Flex project, and I see a warning on the line
"`import com.Adobe.utils.StringUtil;`" and the warning it shows is

```
Multiple markers at this line:
-mx
-The import utils could not be found.
-The import StringUtil could not be found.
```

so what could be the problem?

Well I was wondering what is the difference between `import com.Adobe.utils.StringUtil;` and `import mx.utils.StringUtil;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`com.adobe.utils.StringUtil` and `mx.utils.StringUtil` are different classes. From the [manual](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/StringUtil.html) of `mx.utils.StringUtil`:

> The StringUtil utility class is an all-static class with methods for working with String objects within Flex.

Mark that `within Flex` part.

And [com.adobe.utils.StringUtil](http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/source/browse/trunk/src/com/adobe/utils/StringUtil.as?r=40) is part of Adobe's [as3corelib](http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/) which is a pure AS3 library and offers different methods. You need to add the as3corelib's `StringUtil` to remove the warning.

Comment: how and where do i add it?? and where to get it from??

Comment: You can download the source from the as3corelib project page (the link I have mentioned). You need to place this package under your src directory.

Comment: well i have a question for you....if a mxml file is not set as default application then doesn't it produce the new swf file when we run the project???

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure about this. I'm experienced with pure AS3, but not much experienced with Flex.

Comment: ohk well do you have an idea what does thi mean

"Multiple markers at this line:
- Access of undefined property event
- Call to a possibly undefined method bindable"

Comment: It looks like you have not imported the correct classes. Can you post the code where you are getting the error.

Comment: [Bindable (event=Constants.LOAD_SPECIES)]

Comment: Sorry again :-(. No idea about this error. You can ask a new question with detailed code and information so that other members can help you.

Comment: I am using SDK 4.6 which requires FP 11.1 , when i user FP 11.1 i get ambiguity in JSON which is defined both in as3corelib ans fp 11.1 how do i solve this?

Comment: @taskinoor as3corelib is NOT a pure AS3 library. There are lots of imports from mx libraries. For example, the DateUtil class imports mx.formatters.DateBase.

Answer (score 2):

`com.adobe.utils.StringUtil` is from the as3corelib -- https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib

If this is not included in your project, then flex can't find it. You can either include it or change all imports to use the mx path.  However, there might be a specific reason the as3corelib was included in the old project, so be aware of that.

Comment: so where do i get it from?? and how & where do i add it?? is it that i need to add it to the project?? or the flash builder itself???

Comment: You can just download it from  https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib,  and place the files in the `src` folder in your `src` folder.

Comment: here's a link to the zip file: https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/zipball/master

Comment: i am new to flex and i am given a project to edit the contents appearance on the user interface....so i did the changes on the **mxml** code and in some action script too....and do i have to make changes even in the public website **php** files too?? and i see that one of the **actionscript** file is missing in it, is there a possibility for me to recover it???

Comment: I wouldn't assume you'd have to change any php files, but that depends on if the .swf is talking to php in some way. If you're just changing appearance, then I wouldn't think you would have to.  If you're missing an actionscript file, you'll get the error when you build the file and that will give you enough information to determine where that file should be. If it's a custom .as file, I don't know how you'd go about finding it. Better to determine what the file is that is missing, then come back and let us know.

Comment: well this is an CMS, so there is a lot of stuff interacting with database so i believe that php files should be changed and the mxml file i am editing is not set to default application and the actionscript file (the one missing) which i am referring to is imported into the mxml file.....so i have no clue how to proceed and build the CMS from here on....

Comment: Well your php files are just static files that live on the server, so they don't need to be changed **unless** they have to interact differently with the .swf.  You mentioned that you were only changing the UI of the app, so I would assume that wouldn't change the interaction with the php files at all.  Do you know if the missing action script file is a custom file or not.

Comment: well i mean changing the UI is changing some or the content, which includes renaming, adding, deleting, so the same i have to do with the database as the data has to be stored there and i think the php files do interact with the swf file as i  see a lot of values of the content on the swf file and i don't understand what is meant by actionscript file custom or not??

Comment: Ok, then that would make sense. By custom, I mean did the previous developer write the .as file or is it a as3 component or something?

Comment: i am not sure as i don't find the file in the project folder, but that file is imported into one of the mxml files.....